# Code coverage for code not run locally

Tags: php, unit-testing, http-headers, phpunit, code-coverage

I'm currently developing a simple framework for PHP that manages and dispatches ajax calls. One of its features is that it automatically takes care of sending the appropriate headers depending on what is happening in the backend. During the past couple of days I've started writing a lot of unit tests for [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/) and I'm trying to get a decent [code coverage](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/code-coverage-analysis.html). (Yes, high code coverage by itself doesn't really mean anything, I know. But it still is a good indicator.)

However, because it is (to my knowledge) not possible to send/check headers when PHP is in CLI mode, a lot of tests need to be run through a local webserver. This allows me to easily check the headers and the response body. Unfortunately, the code executed during these tests is, naturally, not tracked by PHPUnit. (Just to be clear: every piece of code that can be checked locally, is checked locally. But everything that is related to headers does not fall into that category.)

I know that I can encapsulate the [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) call and replace it during testing with a mock object. However, then I'd have to re-implement the entire logic of header replacement and what not with all its potential quirks and bugs, so I'd essentially be testing my own `header()`-implementation instead of what's really happening - which is precisely what I *don't* want to do.

So I guess my question is this: can I, somehow, include those "remote calls" in my code coverage report? Or do I (and that's my guess) simply have to accept the fact that I've to miss out on 100% code coverage in order to test under real-world conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to do it.

While ircmaxell's answer was interesting, it didn't really answer my question (hence I marked this answer as accepted).

Answer (score 0):

Well, in practice it's practically impossible to get 100% coverage for an entire code base.  Where you really want 100% is in the core of the application (The libraries and reused components).  The rest is very good to test, but if you'll find there are situations that make it quite difficult to test, so don't stress yourself over a few lines of code that are untestable.

As far as your specific problem, I wouldn't even be writing unit tests for that sort of thing.  What I would write are UI tests using [Selenium HQ](http://seleniumhq.org/).  It's still fully automated, and runs from within PHPUnit, but it uses one or more browsers.  It's really more of an integration or acceptance test than a Unit test, but it works quite well...

Comment: I've experience with Selenium, and while it's a great tool, it really doesn't apply here. Maybe that wasn't clear from how I described my problem.

Comment: Well, given these few references: [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679218/best-way-to-inspect-http-response-headers-with-selenium), [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/3e9e08000e58ccd1/1205af3c6b161cc4?pli=1)...  But if you want to try to describe the problem in a different way, I'll still try to help...

Comment: I'm not having any problems accessing or testing the headers or the response itself, I use Zend_Http_Client for that. I really don't see what additional benefit Selenium has to offer in this particular case.