# capture header param info selenium java

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, selenium

I want to capture the param and header parameter passed from request when page submit in java.
This output we can see in the "net" of firebug.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your question is: "how a selenium test can obtain header parameter(s) from requests / responces?" then the official selenium answer is: [you can't, since it falls outside of "emulating user actions" scope](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141)

There are some workarounds though, I think best of them is [through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679218/the-best-way-to-inspect-http-response-headers-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt understand what you are looking for exactly.
As per my understanding you should look at the getCurrentUrl() method and do the required string operations

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
```