# Retrieve URLs of all external objects in a page incl. dynamically loaded

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I know that I can retrieve all urls from a webpage using many many methods such as 'mechanize', BeautifulSoup and many others.

However, the thing is, some pages might contain urls that are encrypted by Javascript or that are loading from inside a .js file or else.

In Firefox, there is a plugin called "Live http headers", when you open this plugin and visit a web page, the plugin will get you all URL's that has been loaded inside the web page.

I'm looking to do the same thing in python, Any ideas?

**PS:** I managed to do it via PhantomJS and a python webproxy and then parse the python proxy output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver
service_args = [
    '--proxy=127.0.0.1:8899',
    '--proxy-type=http',
    ]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)
driver.get("http://example.com")
print driver.current_url
driver.quit
```

*Is there any better/easier way to do it?*

Comment: Have you looked at something like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)  which you can drive from [python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)?

Comment: You can drive PhantomJS from python through Selenium

Comment: yes i did read it from below url: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

but still cant find the right thing!

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the source of AdBlock+ Firefox extension showed that DOM doesn't provide such a functionality ([only some limited collections](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) like `images`).
The only framework that does is [jQuery Mobile](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pageload.asp) - apparently, only for requests made through that framework.

Instead, a **browser engine** provides events related to making external requests (that would explain why you need to reload a page to see the requests in FireBug). AdBlock+ hooks those and attaches its custom attributes (including the URL and related filter reference) to an appropriate node of the *browser's* object model.

So, you need to either

- write a plugin that would reflect that information into the page, or
- embed a browser engine into your app and receive the events "from the other side", or
- retrieve that information from an existing plugin/built-in feature through the browser's UI with a UI querying tool (e.g. Firefox supports MSAA).

Alternatively, you can do this on network level - with a sniffer or proxy. Then you'll have trouble dealing with HTTPS:

- with a sniffer,

  - Server's private key is required to decrypt the traffic
- a proxy needs to

  - decrypt the response to read the URL
  - re-encrypt it afterwards with its own certificate (probably resulting in a security warning in the browser)

Comment: i did read it from below url: selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html but still cant find the right thing!

Comment: See the update: not available through standard means.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium for it. You should open the page in standart Seleniums way and after that do same as [The best way to inspect HTTP response headers with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679218/the-best-way-to-inspect-http-response-headers-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

To catch all possible URLs that may be generated by JavaScript you will probably have to effectively run a headless browser. One possibility is to use a Webkit library.  Do a google search for "python webkit" to find some possibilities.